# Add text to the end of a file in Python, but without creating a new line

Tags: python

I am attempting to update a series of .csv files to add a missing column delimiter. However, my attempt at appending this character is generating a line break after the delimiter. I see that 'append' is designed exactly for that purpose - to append a new line to a file. Where should I be looking to accomplish this desired output:

```
Input:
Header|
Data

Output:
Header|
Data|
```

For reference I've checked several such SO questions as:
[How do you append to a file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706499/how-do-you-append-to-a-file-in-python)

Code for reference:

```
import os

with open("myNewFile.txt", "a+") as myfile:
    myfile.write("|")
```

For further reference, currently my result looks like:

```
Header|
Data
| (with the pipe character added on a new line)
```

Comment: Please show your code to allow us to see what is wrong.

Comment: How you appending the character? please show us your attempts

Comment: Do you want to append to the last line or also to other lines like the second?

Comment: Hi - I am attempting to append to the very last line, and only the last line (without creating a new line :) ). Due to a formatting issue in the data we were given (missing a final | )

Comment: The file probably already ends in a newline, so you need to replace the newline with `|`, rather than append it to the end

Comment: Ah I see that makes sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @jordanm you probably have a trailing newline in your file.
To remove it you have to read the file first to get its contents in a string.

```
with open("myOldFile.txt", "r") as myfile:
    filestring=myfile.read()
```

Then remove the trailing newline :

```
filestring=filestring.rstrip()
```

Finaly write the new file :

```
with open("myNewFile.txt", "a+") as myfile:
    myfile.write(filestring+"|")
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you should do something like this:

```
print("Hello" , end = ' ')  
print("world!")
```

By this way, the code will `print`:

```
Hello world!
```

For your issue, you have also to write context inside of a file. That is how you might implement it:

```
f = open("demofile2.txt", "a")
f.write("Now the file has more content!")
f.close()
```

If you **only** use `\n` at the end of the string, on the `f.write()` method, then **only** a new line will be printed and then you next `write()` method will start from a new line.

*Use `a` for append, and `w` for overriding the current context and writing again the file form the start.

I hope that helps. Please let me know if it solved your issue.

Comment: Close! I'm trying to add to the end of a file, rather than print it out. Do I need to be doing the same thing, though, and looking for the 'end' of the file? Do I need to read the original file, add the character to it, and then save a new file?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your file ends with a newline, you will have to start a new one.

```
lines = []
with open("myNewFile.txt", "r") as myfile:
    lines = myfile.readlines()
lines[-1] = lines[-1].strip()+"|"
with open("copy.txt", "w") as outfile:
    for line in lines:
        outfile.write(line)
```

Should work as you want.